# How can i trigger only specific freestyleproject if have two jenkins freestyleproject are have same scm git url?

Tags: jenkins, github, webhooks

I have two jenkins freestyle project which have same scm git url. I configure both project to build by trigger github push. if i push to repository, both of them automatically build running. how can i configure only one of them to run build.

Answer (score 0):

For the Jenkins project/job which you want to skip , try enabling under Source Code Management setting in jenkins config:

```
"Don't trigger a build on commit notifications".
```

[image]

When this plugin searches for all projects to build upon a commit from Gitlab, it skips projects with this switch turned on.

Comment: It's not work, both project still build running when i push to repository

Comment: if after setting no trigger in commit notifications, if its still building, try referring this answer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39626345/jenkins-builds-being-triggered-despite-dont-trigger-a-build-on-commit-notifica